# Dropdown spanning the entire navbar

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, navigation

Alright, so I'm doing a web development class and I'm currently working on the last project for the course. I decided that I want a dropdown menu in the navbar so i followed the w3schools tutorial for it, but there is a slight problem. The dropdown, while it looks good, seems to have decided that it's background spanning the entire navbar sounds like a grand idea. [Here's how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOwrc.jpg)

Any of y'all got any idea how to fix this? this is my code

```css
.menu{
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #000;
 max-width: 100%;
 position:relative;
 top: -120px;
 font-size: 16px;
}
.menu a{
 float: left;
 display: block;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 14px 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.menu a:link
.menu a:visited{
 text-decoration: none;
}
.active{
 background-color: #C00;
}
.dropdown{
 float: left;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.dropdown .dopbtn{
 font-size: 16px;
 border: none;
 outline: none;
 color: white;
 padding: 14px 16px;
 background-color: inherit;
 font-family: inherit;
 margin: 0;
}
.menu a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn{
 background-color: #9B0000;
}
.dropdown-content{
 display: none;
 position: static;
 background-color: black;
 max-width: 160px;
 box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px grey;
 z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content a{
 float: left;
 color: white;
 padding: 12px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 text-align: left;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover{
 background-color: #7B0002;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content{
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<Html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<Head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Candlekeep.css" />
<title>Home-Candlekeep</title>
</Head>

<Body class="homepage">
  <header>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=MedievalSharp&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <div class="hwrap">
      <a href="Home.html"><img src="IMG/Logo.png" alt="Homepage" class="logo"></a>
    </div>
    <h1 class="logtxt"><a href="Home.html">Candlekeep</a></h1>
  </header>
   <nav>
    <div class="menu">
      <a href="Home.html" class="active">Home</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a href="DMs.html" class="dropbtn">Dungeon Masters
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
       </a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
             <a href="Phooks.html">Plot Hooks</a>
             <a href="Maps.html">Maps</a>
             <a href="Trap.html">Traps & Puzzles</a>
             <a href="Name.html">Names & Locations</a>
             <a href="campaign.html">Campaign Management</a>
             <a href="Encount.html">Encounters</a>
             <a href="Sheet.html">Character Sheets</a>
    </div>
        </div>
      <a href="Player.html">Players</a>
      <a href="Rsrc.html">General Resources</a> 
    </div>
   </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There were few modifications required but I was able to fix the issue which you mentioned above, hope it helps.

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu {
  background-color: #000;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 32px;
}

.menu a {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 14px 20px;
}

.menu a:link .menu a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.active {
  background-color: #C00;
}

.dropbtn {
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.menu a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #9B0000;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  display: block;
  background-color: #7B0002;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body class="homepage">
  <header>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=MedievalSharp&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </header>
  <nav>
    <div class="menu">
      <a href="Home.html" class="active">Home</a>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <a href="DMs.html" class="dropbtn">Dungeon Masters
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
       </a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="Phooks.html">Plot Hooks</a>
          <a href="Maps.html">Maps</a>
          <a href="Trap.html">Traps & Puzzles</a>
          <a href="Name.html">Names & Locations</a>
          <a href="campaign.html">Campaign Management</a>
          <a href="Encount.html">Encounters</a>
          <a href="Sheet.html">Character Sheets</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="Player.html">Players</a>
      <a href="Rsrc.html">General Resources</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <h1 class="logtxt"><a href="Home.html">Candlekeep</a></h1>
  <div class="hwrap">
    <a href="Home.html"><img src="IMG/Logo.png" alt="Homepage" class="logo"></a>
  </div>
</body>
```